# Is there an Automator action for displaying large text?

Tags: macos, automator

I'm working on an Automator workflow in which I need to take in a text string, do some processing, and then display it to the user, preferably in a manner similar to Address Book's or Quicksilver's "Display in Large Type", but I haven't found any actions to do this. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1):

you could use [growl](http://growl.info/) to display the result.